# Annoying css problems in IE7

Tags: html, css

It works fine in FF, Opera and Chrome. But of cours it's not working ok in IE7.
I have list items which is 73px high, with a red border (a total of 75 px in height).

But I get an unwanted space between each list item. I've tride setting padding and margin to 0 for both `<ul>` and `<li>`, but to no wain.

Here you see the result.

[css f** up in IE http://stiengenterprises.com/download/tmp/css_stuff.jpg](http://stiengenterprises.com/download/tmp/css_stuff.jpg)

And here is my CSS:

```
//<ul with id="articleRotatorList">
#articleRotatorList {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    background: #f1f1f1 url(/img/bg/bg_articleRotatorStripe.png) repeat-y left;
}

#articleRotatorList li {
    height: 73px;
    font-size: 0.90em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

How can I remove the space between the list items?

**UPDATED** 
Added HTML source code:

```
<ul id="articleRotatorList">

                <li id="article_3303">
                    <div class="border"/>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a title="Svangerskap" href="/en/PROSJEKTER/Fersking/Svangerskap/">
                        <h2>Svangerskap</h2>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a... 
                        </a>
                    </div>    
                </li>

                <li id="article_3293">
                    <div class="border"/>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a title="Første leveår" href="/en/PROSJEKTER/Fersking/forste_leveaar/">
                        <h2>Første leveår</h2>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a... 
                        </a>
                    </div>    
                </li>

                <li id="article_3320">
                    <div class="border"/>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a title="Barnesykdommer" href="/en/PROSJEKTER/Fersking/Barnesykdommer/">
                        <h2>Barnesykdommer</h2>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a... 
                        </a>
                    </div>    
                </li>

            </ul>
```

and here is the css for the border / content divs:

```
#articleRotatorList .border {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#articleRotatorList .content {
    width: 210px;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;    
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What if you remove the `float: left`? You don't need that anyway do you?

Comment: I must have float:left on the `<ul>`. Otherwise it will position itself below the image container. I need it on the right side of the image container. But float:left on ul is not the problem.

Comment: You can read about the problem here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/ His solutions doesn't help me though.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the `font-size` being smaller than `1em`. You need to increase the `line-height` a bit. Start with `1.10em`:

```
#articleRotatorList li {
    height: 73px;
    font-size: 0.90em;
    line-height: 1.10em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: How exactly is line height inside the list items affecting space between list items on the outside? Increasing / decreasing line-height inside list item, does nothing to remove space between list items.

Answer (score 0):

As BalusC suggested, this is most likely a font-size/line-height issue, however I believe you may find success by setting both to 0 on the ul tag, and re-initializing them on the li tag. Yes, it sucks.

Comment: Setting `line-height: 0px;` on `#articleRotatorList` does nothing except putting all text on one line. Still got the space between the `<li>`.

Comment: That isn't all of what I suggested :( line height and font size to 0 in the ul tag, and reset it back to what you want in the li tag. If you had this page live somewhere, I'd be happy to do more than make a wild guess at something IE7 has done to me in the past :P

Comment: I have found a work-around to the problem. It looks like it's a well known issue: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/.